# Failed to load resource from datatables cdn

Tags: html, datatables

I get this error using cdn

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Here is my script

```
<script src="cdn.datatables.net/1.12.1/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css"></script>
    <script src="cdn.datatables.net/1.12.1/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <script src="cdn.datatables.net/1.12.1/js/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#example').DataTable();
      } );
    </script>
```

I tried inspecting the code in my browser. Most other solutions are for local downloaded directory errors.

Answer (score 0):

added https:// before link and jquery cdn.
Please try with this:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
</head>

<body>
  
<div class="container">
  <h2>Basic Table</h2>
          
  <table class="table" id="example">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Firstname</th>
        <th>Lastname</th>
        <th>Email</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>John</td>
        <td>Doe</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Mary</td>
        <td>Moe</td>
        <td>mary@example.com</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>July</td>
        <td>Dooley</td>
        <td>july@example.com</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
    
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.12.1/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.12.1/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#example').DataTable();
      });
    </script>


</body>

</html>
```